# Regex code for 2 words that start with the same letter

Tags: regex

the user has the fill in 2 words in a field, I need to regex to code the check if they both start with the same letter. example: blue bear

Comment: Excellent problem description.  Now what have you tried?  We’ll help you fix it, but this is not a code writing service; you need to do some work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this regex:

```
^(\w)\w*\s+\1\w*$
```

This regex check string contains only 2 words (In regex definition, word is \w metacharacter)
And the first character in first word is a capture group, and it is needed to repeat in the first character in second word.

Comment: Somewhat better but than Ian’s answer, but fails with français words which contain accented characters, and allows strange characters in words like numbers and underscores (which programmers have considered as word characters, but mundane people would not.)

Answer (score -2):

Use the `\#` to refer to previous capture groups (`(...)`). In this following example, I use `\1` to refer to the first letter of the first word.

Here you go.

```js
    let regex = /(.).* \1.*/;
    let tests = [
      "brown bear",
      "Green Goblin",
      "Peter Parker",
      "Clark Kent",
      "Lois Lane"
      ];
      
    
    console.log(tests.filter((test) => test.match(regex)));
```

Comment: But it also matches `"   "` and `"As Good As It Gets"` ... both of which are odd for the two word requirement.

Comment: The input is defined as "2 words in a field". This regex is provided to solve that. If the regex is also required to do further validation, e.g. require exactly two words, that should be specified. We both made assumptions. I provided an answer. Whatever.

Comment: It returns true for a string of exactly 3 spaces (my first case above); you have to admit that’s a bit of a stretch, even with the ill defined requirements of the question.

Comment: What are you arguing about? Assume the 2-word requirement is met prior to using this regex. You are given a two word string. Given. You are not given an arbitrary string. You are given a two word string.